# Purchases.getOfferings(); hangs after upgrading RevenueCat to latest

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

Here are the packages I have in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
firebase_core_web: ^1.1.0
cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.3
firebase_core: ^1.7.0
firebase_auth: ^3.1.2
provider: ^6.0.1
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.8
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.2
firebase_analytics: ^8.3.3
purchases_flutter: ^3.0.0
```

I run everything in Flutter stable channel version 2.5.2.
I tried using flutter channel beta version 2.6.0-5.2.pre as well.

The iOS version of the phone is 15.0.1. And I run tests on Iphone 7 (physical device, not a simulator). XCode version is 13.0. MAC OS is Big Sur 11.6 (with M1 chip).

The app works perfectly fine on Android but it hangs at the start of the app when I call the following function:

```
Offerings rcOfferings;
rcOfferings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
```

And the `getOfferings()` function never returns.. It was working perfectly fine before..

During the update procedure, the only change I made is the following:
Remove the following:  `Purchases.identify(rcAppUserId);`
And instead use:  `Purchases.logIn(rcAppUserId);`

Is this a known issue? What can be potential reasons for the getOfferings() function never returning anything…? It hangs when this function is called and the app never starts…

---

ADDENDUM

I enabled logs and here is what I see:

```
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ Debug logging enabled
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ SDK Version - 3.12.3
[Purchases] - DEBUG:  Initial App User ID - (null)
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ Sending latest PurchaserInfo to delegate.
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ Delegate set
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ There are no requests currently running, starting request GET /subscribers/1634905166007
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request started: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request started: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166/offerings
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request completed with status: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166/offerings 304

[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ Requesting products from the store with identifiers: {(
    "product_1",
    "product_2",
    "product_3",
    "product_4",
    "product_5",
    "product_6"
)}
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request completed with status: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166007 304
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ Serial request done: GET /subscribers/1634905166007, 0 requests left in the queue
flutter:
Init Platform State RevenueCat - DONE!
flutter:
Get offerings - RevenueCat
[tcp] tcp_output [C4.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=2740821213, ack=1928912997, win=4095 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1928912997, snd_una=2740821136
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 12 ("SKProductsRequest"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
flutter:
CALLING RevenueCat getRcOfferings() function now...
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ No cached Offerings, fetching from network
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request started: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166/offerings
[Purchases] - DEBUG: ℹ️ API request completed with status: GET /v1/subscribers/1634905166/offerings 304
[tcp] tcp_output [C5.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=2802284821, ack=658575777, win=4103 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=658575777, snd_una=2802284744
```

As seen above, it lists the products in the beginning (and I do not really understand in which step it does that).

The line saying “CALLING RevenueCat getRcOfferings() function now...” is the place where getOfferings() function is called and the app hangs there while waiting… When I say hangs, it keeps waiting for this async call to complete.

Hoping that this additional information will help to get some help...

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few reports of folks running into this, like here:

https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/ios-15-xcode-13-rcpurchases-sharedpurchases-offeringswithcompletionblock-is-never-called-492

It seems like this is happening with older sandbox accounts, due to StoreKit’s `SKProductsRequest` just hanging. The RevenueCat team is currently looking into it to come up with solutions.

In the meantime, creating a new sandbox user has reportedly been working well for other RevenueCat users.

Could you give it a try?